# Production Database Cloning for Staging Server

Tags: database, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I have my production Database filled with live data from sensor.

I need a way that can clone/replicate the data in another database where I can use for staging as sometimes I need to feed it test inputs without messing up the production database.

What is the best way to go about doing that automatically so as new data coming in to the production DB would be copied immediately on the staging DB but if I manually add data to the staging DB it wont be copied back to the production DB

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you easily be able to do this within meteor as it only really talks to one database at a time. It can be done but would be rather complex to implement by directly playing with the MongoDB driver.

If I was you, I’d be looking at trying to get your sensor to write independently to both the production and staging databases.